# Shibboleth with custom web application's own SignOn mechanism

Tags: authentication, servlet-filters, shibboleth

We are developing a web application that has its own SignOn mechanism (login mechanism using username and password). The SignOn mechanism is implemented using a Web Application Filter)

The web application container is Apache Tomcat 6.0

The User may also choose to login through Shibboleth authentication. That is, to access our Web Application, the user may choose either be authenticated using Shibboleth, or using our own SignOn mechanism which is web application filter-based.

Is it technically feasible to support both Shibboleth Authentication, and a Web Application Filter based SignOn mechanism?

If it's feasible, from the Web Application Filter side, how do we check if a user was authenticated already by Shibboleth? Is there some Shibboleth Authentication token, or Shibboleth User session?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you use Apache in front of your Tomcat?

Comment: I use Apache HTTPD 2.2 in front of my web application contained by Apache Tomcat 7.0.42 (upgraded from Apache Tomcat 6.0)

Comment: Ok, you can use mod_shib_22.so module on your Apache to integrate the SP. See https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/NativeSPApacheConfig

Comment: How do I uniquely identify a Shibboleth authenticated user? I've read about Shib-persistent-id. But both request.getAttribute("Shib-persistent-id") and request.getHeader("Shib-persistent-id") returns null. I verified that the user was authencticated because request.getAttribute("Shib-Identity-Provider") returns properly the entityId of my Shibboleth Identity Provider.

Comment: It depends on the IdP. Use https://your-host/Shibboleth.sso/Session to see what attributes your IdP have sent and choose an unique attribute like "HTTP_USER"

Comment: Provided the IdP is configured to send the user unique identifier attribute, please confirm if it is correct that to access it on the Service Provider side (or the custom web application), is through request.getAttribute("Shib-persistent-id") or request.getHeader("Shib-persistent-id"). Thanks.

Comment: Yes, after a succesful auth use the request.getAttribute("YOUR_ATTRIB") or request.getHeader("YOUR_ATTRIB") where YOUR_ATTRIB id the name of the user unique identifier attribute sent by your IdP (sometimes attribute needs to e prefixed by HTTP_ so try also HTTP_YOUR_ATTRIB)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you refer to Shibboleth SP (the Service Provider component) and also that you will need Shibboleth IdP (an Identity Provider) to provide the actual authentication.

**...And yes, it is feasible** and the two methods can easily coexist.

When the user is successfully authenticated by Shibboleth SP (using the Identity Provider) it place the well-known session attributes in the HTTP request attributes and headers.

You can view the session attributes visiting:

```
https://your-host/Shibboleth.sso/Session
```

So, Inside your application you can check the presence and the value of those attributes like:

```
request.getAttribute("NAME_OF_THE_ATTRIBUTE_IN_SESSION")
request.getHeader("NAME_OF_THE_ATTRIBUTE_IN_SESSION")
```

Then, using Shibboleth attributes you can do the necessary operations to *allow* or *deny* the user authentication.

See [this](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/NativeSPEnableApplication) official wiki to understand how "Shibbolize" an Application and [this](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/NativeSPAttributeAccess) for accessing attributes.

I would recommend to start reading from the start [this clear and comprehensive wiki](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/Installation+and+Configuration) on Shibboleth SP and IdP installation and configuration.